# Arrangement of Flowers

Tags: combinatorics

I found this question in a textbook:

> A florist is arranging flowers in centerpieces at each of four tables at an event. If he has 61 flowers in total, which of the following statements are true?
>
> - (I) one table has no more than 13 flowers
> - (II) one table has at least 16 flowers
> - (III) two of the tables have at least 31 flowers combined

The question is multiple choice with

- (A) II only
- (B) I and II only
- (C) I and III only
- (D) II and III only
- (E) I, II and III only

The textbook says the correct option is (D) and I agree with it. However, I do not know why my solution is wrong. This is my solution:

Let the tables be R, S, T and U. Let table R have 13 flowers, table S 17 flowers and tables T and U 31 flowers. Now, $13+17+31=61$. Hence option (E) seem correct. Please what I'm I getting wrong?

Comment: The question isn't asking for you to create an arrangement satisfying them, it's asking which of (I), (II) and (III) *must* hold no matter how you arrange the flowers.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking whether all possible arrangements meet the requirements (not just one specific arrangement).  So for instance I can fail with 15, 15, 15, 16 flowers.